# 1.11 help with /summon command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Why won't this command work in minecraft 1.11

```
/summon item ~ ~-1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[],display:{Name:"Elixir Collector"},EntityTag:{id:"pig",CustomName:"farm2"}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 1.11, the `id` value within the `EntityTag` compound must contain the entire entity ID, including the namespace (i.e. "minecraft:pig" instead of "pig").

As well, items will only have the enchantment glint in 1.11 if the `ench` list contains a compound within it, rather than simply existing. The enchantment ID will default to 0 (Protection) if not specified, so you would otherwise need to set it to an invalid enchantment ID such as -1:

```
/summon item ~ ~-1 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:spawn_egg,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:-1s}],display:{Name:"Elixir Collector"},EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:pig",CustomName:"farm2"}}}}
```